# How do I refer to a section in a markdown page from source code for doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I want to link from my source code to a specific section in one of the project documentation markdown files. I can link to the file by using \ref filename.md. I cannot link to a section in that file with \ref sec_somesection as that is unrecognized.

How can I link to a specific section (or subsection etc)?

Comment: Can I assume you have used a doxygen `\section blah title` in the markdown (and not just a markdown `#` section title)?

Comment: @Cheeseminer: yes you can. I have several \section and \subsections.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using named sections, just use the \ref command to create links to them.
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref

You can also use the \anchor command on your secondary pages, and link to it, without having to create a section.